# How to call protocol extensions initializers in designated initializers?

Tags: swift, class, swift2, designated-initializer, protocol-extension

I'm trying to inject a protocol extension initializer into an existing class's designated initializer. I don't think there's a way around it without overriding the designated initializer from the class, then call the protocol extension initializer within.

Below is what I'm trying, specifically with the `UIViewController` class:

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController, MyProtocol {

    var locationManager: CLLocationManager?
    var lastRendered: NSDate?

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        // TODO: How to call MyProtocol initializer?
        // (self as MyProtocol).init(aDecoder) // Didn't compile
    }

}

protocol MyProtocol: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var locationManager: CLLocationManager? { get set }
    var lastRendered: NSDate? { get set }

    init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
}

extension MyProtocol where Self: UIViewController {

    // Possible to inject this into initialization process?
    init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupLocationManager()
    }

    func setupLocationManager() {
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager?.delegate = self
        locationManager?.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers
        locationManager?.distanceFilter = 1000.0
        locationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        // TODO
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        // TODO
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
        // TODO
    }
}
```

Is there a way to make use of protocol extensions initializers so it gets called automatically during the framework's existing initialization process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't *need* to call a different initializer; you're already initializing. Moreover, you don't need to cast `self` to MyProtocol; you've already declared that it adopt MyProtocol. Plus, you've already injected MyProtocol's `setupLocationManager` into FirstViewController, because your FirstViewController already adopts MyProtocol and the extension on MyProtocol is aimed at UIViewController, the superclass of FirstViewController.

So, the method is already injected; now just go right ahead and call the injected method right there in the initializer you're already running. The following pared-down version of your code compiles perfectly well:

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController, MyProtocol {
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager?

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.setupLocationManager() // no problem!
    }
}

protocol MyProtocol: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    // this next line is necessary so that
    // ...setupLocationManager can refer to `self.locationManager`
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager? { get set }
}

extension MyProtocol where Self: UIViewController {
    func setupLocationManager() {
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        // ... etc.
    }
    // ... etc.
}
```